# How to unlock TYPO's Install Tool (/typo3/install.php)?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

After adding an empty text file called 'ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL" in the 'typo3conf' folder the Install Tool is still locked when I visit hostname/typo3/install.php.

Some background information: I just uploaded all TYPO3 files to a remote host and am trying to get it to display the TYPO3 website. When I logged into the backend I got the following error:

## 1533822084 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Crypto\PasswordHashing\InvalidPasswordHashException

Configured default hash method
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Crypto\PasswordHashing\Argon2iPasswordHash is not available. If the instance has just been upgraded, please log in to
the standalone install tool at typo3/install.php to fix this. Follow
the wiki link for more details.

This error referred to this wiki page: https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1533822084

Here it is suggested to:

> Call the standalone install tool and log in once. This should detect that argon2i is not available and will configure a different default hash mechanism. A backend login should be possible afterwards.

Which is what I am stuck on since the Install Tool is locked.

Comment: You wrote: " I just uploaded all TYPO3 files to a remote host and am trying to get it to display the TYPO3 website." How did you upload? You can't upload TYPO3 by FTP. You definitely need SSH.

Comment: I used SFTP, so should be okay :)

Comment: No, it is definitely not okay!

Comment: SFTP uses SSH, so I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you visit for the first time the address `https://yoursite.com/typo3/install.php` you should see the following screen:

[image: locked Install Tool screen]

As you wrote, you have to add a file `ENABLE_INSTALL_TOOL` (without extension) in the folder `/typo3conf/` of your TYPO3 installation; the file can be empty.

After you have done that and refreshed the same page, you should see:

[image: locked Install Tool 2]

If you have not changed it (which is recommended) , the password should be the same password as the one of the first administrator user you have created during the installation.

If you have changed it and don't remember it, follow the on screen instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the official installation guide:

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/en-us/QuickInstall/GetAndUnpack/Index.html

You need SSH access to your remote server. FTP or SFTP is not enough because the symlinks are not uploaded.

You need to transfer a zip- or tar.gz-file to the server and unpack it there. Never unpack them on your machine and transfer the files to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue in Typo3 10 in CentOS 8

The argon2 password hash algorithm only in PHP >= 7.4, not in previous versions in CentOS 8.

In 7.2 / 7.3, argon2 is part of the "standard" extension and is disabled in RH build as libargon2 is not available in RHEL / CentOS

So if you can upgrade to PHP 7.4 it would work.

Alternative method when in PHP 7.3
in LocalConfiguration.php set

```
'installToolPassword' => '$2y$12$kB0JLQcbADywtxtxjoBoUOrCSk0RHhh/zuKDbFrtAYlr8fUlZ/1Em',
'passwordHashing' => [
        'className' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Crypto\\PasswordHashing\\BcryptPasswordHash',
```

Open install tool ursite/typo3/install.php
password is 'password' (installToolPassword hash value above)

Now create an new admin and use that to login to backend and reset the passwords of other admins